# Spaces not working on existing span

Tags: html, wysiwyg, froala

I have been using froala Editor with Google Chrome and everything is fine. I met a client who uses Firefox who needed to press the space-bar twice in order to get a single space. Pressing it once made the space appear, only to disappear as soon as you start typing the next word.

The issue happens when the content is pre-loaded and the user wants to append text to an existing "<span>" element.

Unlike the guy with this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647452/froala-editor-not-adding-whitespace-on-pressing-spacebar-in-firebox-browser-it) , I am not getting any error at all in my console.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue? How do I resolve it so that my Firefox users can only press space-bar once to get a single space instead of pressing twice?

Thank you in advance for your assistance. If it helps, the client uses the latest Firefox always and so do I.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a little css to that `span` tag, `display: inline-block;` and then check if it resolves your problem.

Comment: The issue still remains, this doesn's solve the issue. The way spaces are being removed feels like there is javascript that is actively doing the removing when I am typing. If I press "Enter" for a new line, I can type spaces normally in that new line, the css rules in the inspector are the same for the old and the new line

Comment: I updated to the latest version (2.7.1) and the problem seems to be gone. I am still doing tests and I will provide feedback afterwards. Thanks